# Textarea - required, but with default text

Tags: javascript, html

How can I set two attributes (default text, which hides after click and required) for textarea?

```
  <textarea name="dedication" id="dedTextArea" required onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value=''" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue">Default text</textarea>
```

HTML "thinks" that `Default text` is my input. How Can I repair it?
Thanks for all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used the attribute `placeholder` for the "default text which hides after click". However be aware that `placeholder` only works on browsers with HTML5 support. You are setting required correctly, it also just doesn't work on some browsers.

```
<textarea name="dedication" id="dedTextArea" 
     required
     placeholder="default text"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind compatibility the easy solution is to use `placeholder`.

```
<textarea placeholder="Default text"></textarea>
```

[This does not work in older browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=placeholder), most notably IE9 and lower.

Answer (score 1):

```
<textarea 
   onfocus="if (this.value == this.defaultValue) { this.value='' }" 
   onblur="if (this.value=='') { this.value = this.defaultValue" }>
   Enter some text!
</textarea>
```

Here is a JS Fiddle demonstrating it: http://jsfiddle.net/Xhawp/1/

Comment: Thinking about it this is probably what he wants instead of placeholder since he wants the field to be required but to have a default value.

Answer (score 0):

As your tagging HTML5 if the default is a single line why not just;

```
 <textarea name="dedication" id="dedTextArea" placeholder="Default text"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the default text does disappear after clicking (in Chrome), but if you want a placeholder instead of the actual text, use the below:

```
 <textarea name="dedication" id="dedTextArea" required onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value=''" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue" placeholder="Default Text"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

use placeholder attribute

```
<textarea name="dedication" id="dedTextArea" required placeholder="Default text"></textarea>
```